# Using docker --squash in docker-compose when building images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is there a way to use the `--squash` option in docker-compose when building new docker images? Right now they have implemented `--squash` in docker as of 6 months ago, but I have not seen any docs about how to use this in docker-compose.yml.

Is there a work around here? (I see an open issue filed requesting this [feature](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4235))

Comment: Unfortunately because of this request they intend to completely remove feature from docker https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34565

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `--squash`, you can use [Docker multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Here is a simple example for a Python app that uses the Django web framework. We want to separate out the testing dependencies into a different image, so that we do not deploy the testing dependencies to production. Additionally, we want to separate our automated documentation utilities from our test utilities.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
# the AS keyword lets us name the image
FROM python:3.6.7 AS base
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install django

# base is the image we have defined above
FROM base AS testing
RUN pip install pytest

# same base as above
FROM base AS documentation
RUN pip install sphinx
```

In order to use this file to build different images, we need the `--target` flag for `docker build`. The argument of `--target` should name the name of the image after the `AS` keyword in the Dockerfile.

Build the base image:

`docker build --target base --tag base .`

Build the testing image:

`docker build --target testing --tag testing .`

Build the documentation image:

`docker build --target documentation --tag documentation .`

This lets you build images that branch from the same base image, which can significantly reduce build-time for larger images.

You can also use multi-stage builds in Docker Compose. As of version 3.4 of `docker-compose.yml`, you can use the `target` keyword in your YAML.

Here is a `docker-compose.yml` file that references the `Dockerfile` above:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    testing:
        build:
            context: .
            target: testing
    documentation:
        build:
            context: .
            target: documentation
```

If you run `docker-compose build` using this `docker-compose.yml`, it will build the `testing` and `documentation` images in the `Dockerfile`. As with any other `docker-compose.yml`, you can also add ports, environment variables, runtime commands, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve squash result with trick like

```
FROM oracle AS needs-squashing
ENV NEEDED_VAR some_value
COPY ./giant.zip ./somewhere/giant.zip
RUN echo "install giant in zip"
RUN rm ./somewhere/giant.zip

FROM scratch
COPY --from=needs-squashing / /
```

Comment: Note that when you do this, you will lose ENV settings, the entrypoint definition, and other metadata, all you copy is the filesystem.